# Further possible meanings of “Verkehr”

Tags: translation, meaning

I came across the word *Verkehr*. In dictionaries I only found the translation of the word to mean *traffic* or *transportation*. However, it seems that in the context, the word means much more.

I read the word in a book by Karl Marx. In the works of Karl Marx in English the word is often translated by *exchange*. What can the word *Verkehr* mean in other contexts in German?

Comment: Thank you for changes. Yes, you are correct. I mean it: What can the word Verkehr mean in other contexts in German?

Comment: "Verkehr" in the sense of "trade" is not a primary meaning. It was originally a compound "Warenverkehr" or "Güterverkehr", which then became common enough to be clipped back to "Verkehr".

Answer (score 12):

Verkehr = traffic

> Um ungefähr 17 Uhr ist der **Verkehr** auf den Straßen sehr stark.
>   At about 5 pm the **traffic** on the road is very heavy.

Verkehr = communication

> Ich stehe in ständigem E-Mail-**Verkehr** mit dem Chef.
>   I am in a constant e-mail **communication** with the boss.

Verkehr = circulation

> Niemand weiß genau, vielen Falschgeld derzeit im **Verkehr** ist.
>   Nobody knows exactly, how many counterfeit money is in **circulation** now.

Verkehr = intercourse

> Wenn ein Mann und eine Frau **Verkehr** haben, kann die Frau schwanger werden.
>   When a man and a woman have **intercourse**, the woman can get pregnant.

Verkehr = contact

> Beim **Verkehr** mit Menschen aus anderen Kulturen kann es zu Missverständnissen kommen.
>   At the **contact** with people from other cultures there can be missunderstandings.

This list is not complete. *Verkehr* has many more meanings, but they all are very similar to those in this list.
You can also use it as a verb as *verkehren*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It can mean *traffic* or *transport*, but also *association*, *communication*, *dealings* (in a commercial sense) or *intercourse* (in all meanings of the term).

Comment: And interaction.